# How to set 20 record per page when i rendering reports in SSRS 2008?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created Report in `SSRS-2008` using Tablix Data region.

My dataset returning 1000 rows. When rendering into pdf i have to display 20 rows per page.

*I'm new to SSRS so please explain me step by step solution.*

Answer (score 4):

Go to the properties and find:

*Report, Page--->InteractiveSize---> Height*

Change the height properties by 5.5 and you will be able to show 20 rows per page.

Comment: While not specifically setting you up for exactly 20 rows per page, this is a **much simpler** answer to the more general question of "How do I limit the # of rows per page in a tablix-based SSRS report?", which I found quite helpful.  It's an easy setting to overlook or forget about, but very important for usability.

Answer (score 3):

First result on Google for "SSRS Items per page" was:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic490774-147-1.aspx

From that discussion thread, it looks like creating a group and then grouping on `=Ceiling((RowNumber(Nothing)) / 20)` will give you what you want. You'll need to change the group properties to start a new page at each instance of the group.

As for "step by step," I'm not sure what you are hoping for: do you need help creating a report? Creating groups? Opening Visual Studio?

Comment: I am having a table in my SSRS 2008 report.
The table contains more than 100 rows. the user has to scroll down to view the data. In order to avoid this, i want to implement paging in the table so that each page on the report shows 20 records in the table and the data of the table is split in 5 pages.

Comment: +1. @jay an alternative solution to your problem is to set the interactive size for height to screen size height.