# SSRS Page Break after custom # of group

Tags: pdf, reporting-services

I am working on a SSRS report. It is a Tablix with 1 group by city. I would like to have 4-5 records per printer page in PDF. Currently, it is printing 1 record per printed page. This is because I have set a hard page break after each group. I can remove that hard page break but I'm unsure how to get 4-5 on each printed page. I'm not that good with SSRS expressions. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840455/how-to-set-20-record-per-page-when-i-rendering-reports-in-ssrs-2008, you need to create another group above your current group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle this by creating another column in your dataset which groups 4 or 5 cities. say the first 5 as 1, then the next 5 as 2 etc.. and then add a parent group to your city group using this column.. then  set your page break on that group..

Comment: This seems to get me half way there. There are many empty blank pages in actual printout. HOw do I get rid of the blank pages? thank you

Comment: Forget that last comment. I got rid of the blank pages. However, a few pages only has 2 items per group where I have asked for 3 items per group. Thougths?

Comment: What does your dataset look like for the group's that has only 2 items per page? Ensure page breaks are turned off for the city group as well.